# Logstash not importing data

Tags: elasticsearch, import, logstash, kibana, elk

I am working on an ELK stack setup I want to import data from a csv file from my PC to elasticsearch via logstash. Elasticsearch and Kibana is working properly.

Here is my `logstash.conf` file:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "C:/Users/aron/Desktop/es/archive/weapons.csv"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "NUL"
    }
}
filter {
    csv {
        separator => ","
        columns => ["name", "type", "country"]
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["http://localhost:9200/"]
        index => "weapons"
        document_type => "ww2_weapon"
    }
    stdout {}
}
```

And a sample row data from my .csv file looks like this:

| Name | Type | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10.5 cm Kanone 17 | Field Gun | Germany |

German characters are all showing up.

I am running logstash via: `logstash.bat -f path/to/logstash.conf`

It starts working but it freezes and becomes unresponsive along the way, here is a screenshot of stdout

[image]

In kibana, it created the index and imported 2 documents but the data is all messed up. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "the data is all messed up"?

Comment: I cant see any data its just metadata like hosts, message, original, event and even the columns are indexed like ```""""name,type,country\n
"""```

Answer (score 0):

If your task is only to import that CSV you better use the file upload in Kibana.
Should be available under the following link (for Kibana > v8):
`<your Kibana domain>/app/home#/tutorial_directory/fileDataViz`

Logstash is used if you want to do this job on a regular basis with new files coming in over time.

Comment: Yes, I know. But I want to try out logstash.

Comment: ok got it. The freeze can happen when the file is big. How much MB has the file?
The screenshot you shared looks like the parsing works. Is there any index template (re-)defining the mapping before it gets into Kibana?

Comment: The file is not big, it has 386 rows. A grand total of 17 KB. As for the mapping, I didn't setup anything in Kibana, no index, no mapping, nothing. Basically i let logstash create the index and mapping for me.

Comment: I notive there's a /r after all the fields, could this be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below one. It is running perfectly on my machine.

```
input {
    file {
    path => "path/filename.csv" 
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "NULL"
  }
 
}
filter {
    csv {
        separator => ","
        columns => ["field1","field2",...]
  }
}


output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "https://localhost:9200"
        user => "username"                       ------> if any
        password => "password"                   ------> if any
        index => "indexname"
        document_type => "doc_type"
        
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's still hanging on my machine. What csv are you using? I'm having a hard time figuring out if the problem is with my csv or with the configuration file.